# problem with min function in R getting error: InfWarning: no non-missing arguments to min; returning InfWarning: no non-missing arguments to min

Tags: r, max, warnings, min

I have been working with a data frame similar to the one below (though much larger. Every time I run the min function on this data frame when there are NA values I get this warning repeated thousands of times "InfWarning: no non-missing arguments to min; returning InfWarning: no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf". This happens even when I include the argument. na.rm=T. The warning occurs so many time that my R stops responding. In the below code the dataframe is small enough that the code will run despite the warning. In reality I'm working with a much larger data set.

```
naive<-structure(list(numstint = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), format.stata = "%10.0g"), release_date = c(17584, 
19195, NA, NA, 17960, 18465, 18792, 19111, 19268, 20526, 18739, 
19770, 18338, 18338, 17374, 17374, 17720, 19557, 20328, 20328, 
20328, NA, NA, 17609, 20262, 18100, 18347, 18067, 19418, 19418, 
19418, 19418, 19418, 19418, 19418, 19418, 19506, 20694, 18974, 
20263, NA, NA, 18094, 18735, 18735, 19841, 18846, 20536, 20536, 
20536, 20536, 20536, 18472, 20080, 18708, 19351, 19625, 19842, 
NA, 20557, 19675, 18108, 18819, NA, 20673, 19446, 19446, 19712, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18737, 17737, 18354, 18354, 19222, 17267, 
18045, 17719, 19536, 19408, 20204, 18951, 18951, 18951, 18951, 
18951, 18951, 18951, 18951, 18951, 18951, 18951, NA, NA, 19001, 
19484), maxrls = c(19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 
19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 
19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 
19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 
19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 
19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 
19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 
19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 
19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 
19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 
19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 
19724, 19724, 19724, 19724), tyear3 = c(18679, 20290, NA, NA, 
19055, 19560, 19887, 20206, 20363, NA, 19834, NA, 19433, 19433, 
18469, 18469, 18815, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18704, NA, 19195, 
NA, 19162, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20601, NA, 20069, 
NA, NA, NA, 19189, 19830, 19830, NA, 19941, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
19567, NA, 19803, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20770, 19203, NA, NA, NA, 
20541, 20541, 20807, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19832, 18832, NA, 
NA, NA, 18362, NA, 18814, NA, 20503, NA, 20046, 20046, 20046, 
20046, 20046, 20046, 20046, 20046, 20046, 20046, 20046, NA, NA, 
20096, NA), id = structure(c(1074, 1165, 1431, 1934, 2285, 2459, 
2884, 3171, 4037, 4371, 5091, 5091, 5314, 5314, 5396, 5396, 5434, 
5434, 6277, 6277, 6277, 6277, 6379, 6613, 6724, 7231, 7231, 7649, 
7649, 7649, 7649, 7649, 7649, 7649, 7649, 7649, 8371, 8506, 8956, 
9667, 10727, 10727, 11320, 11497, 11497, 11497, 12413, 12606, 
12606, 12606, 12606, 12606, 14000, 15548, 15578, 15578, 15578, 
15578, 16063, 16303, 17132, 17732, 17732, 17732, 18258, 18416, 
18416, 18616, 18647, 18647, 18647, 18691, 18691, 18691, 18970, 
19327, 19327, 19327, 19327, 19535, 19535, 19640, 19640, 19754, 
19754, 19888, 19888, 19888, 19888, 19888, 19888, 19888, 19888, 
19888, 19888, 19888, 19920, 20182, 20438, 20438), format.stata = "%12.0g")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), groups = structure(list(
    id = structure(c(1074, 1165, 1431, 1934, 2285, 2459, 2884, 
    3171, 4037, 4371, 5091, 5314, 5396, 5434, 6277, 6379, 6613, 
    6724, 7231, 7649, 8371, 8506, 8956, 9667, 10727, 11320, 11497, 
    12413, 12606, 14000, 15548, 15578, 16063, 16303, 17132, 17732, 
    18258, 18416, 18616, 18647, 18691, 18970, 19327, 19535, 19640, 
    19754, 19888, 19920, 20182, 20438), format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
        10L, 11:12, 13:14, 15:16, 17:18, 19:22, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
        26:27, 28:36, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41:42, 43L, 44:46, 
        47L, 48:52, 53L, 54L, 55:58, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62:64, 65L, 
        66:67, 68L, 69:71, 72:74, 75L, 76:79, 80:81, 82:83, 84:85, 
        86:96, 97L, 98L, 99:100), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -50L), .drop = TRUE))

naive <- naive%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  mutate(year3 = min(tyear3 , na.rm=T))
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is the `min()` function not finding anything:

```
> min(c())

[1] Inf
Warning message:
In min(c()) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Looks like you are only replicating the tyear3 column, with a new name (year3). Since the id its unique, the minimun for every id is the same observation. The output of:

```
> naive %>% group_by(id)

 # A tibble: 100 x 5
 # Groups:   id [50]
   numstint release_date maxrls tyear3    id
      <dbl>        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1        1        17584  19724  18679  1074
 2        1        19195  19724  20290  1165
 3        1           NA  19724     NA  1431
 4        1           NA  19724     NA  1934
 5        1        17960  19724  19055  2285
 6        1        18465  19724  19560  2459
 7        1        18792  19724  19887  2884
 8        1        19111  19724  20206  3171
 9        1        19268  19724  20363  4037
10        1        20526  19724     NA  4371
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Has the same rows than the minimun:

```
> naive %>% group_by(id) %>%  mutate(year3 = min(tyear3 , na.rm = T))

# A tibble: 100 x 6
# Groups:   id [50]
   numstint release_date maxrls tyear3    id year3
      <dbl>        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1        1        17584  19724  18679  1074 18679
 2        1        19195  19724  20290  1165 20290
 3        1           NA  19724     NA  1431   Inf
 4        1           NA  19724     NA  1934   Inf
 5        1        17960  19724  19055  2285 19055
 6        1        18465  19724  19560  2459 19560
 7        1        18792  19724  19887  2884 19887
 8        1        19111  19724  20206  3171 20206
 9        1        19268  19724  20363  4037 20363
10        1        20526  19724     NA  4371   Inf
# ... with 90 more rows
There were 36 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```